# Remover botão 'Continuar comprando' do checkout no Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Botão continuar comprando]

Olá, alguém sabe como remover as informações e o botão 'continuar comprando' do checkout no Woocommerce? No lugar, gostaria de acrescentar a descrição do kit que está sendo comprado.

Gostaria de deixar conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: Assim]

Comment: A maneira mais fácil é comentar este botão diretamente no código do seu tema.

Answer (score 1):

Procurando por *"Continue Shopping"* no código do plugin, traz ao arquivo [`wc-cart-functions.php#L88`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L88), onde tem este filtro:

```php
wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
```

O seguinte código no seu `functions.php` ou plugin personalizado removeria o aviso:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', '__return_empty_string' );
# pode tentar __return_null também
```

Se ficar algum rastro, provavelmente deverá ser removido com CSS ou edição do arquivo relevante no *theme/child-theme* usado no site.

E para chegar ao resultado que descreve, deve filtrar por `product_id` e usar algo como:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', function( $msg, $id ){
    if( $id == SEU_PRODUCT_ID ) $msg = "Produto tal";
    return $msg;
}, 10, 2 );
```